# How do I fix my "My Documents"?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, my-documents

I had a harddrive failure (Click of death) which is where "My Documents" was located. Now, when I try to boot Windows XP, it cannot start up. How do I fix the issue so I can boot up? Do I just need to add a new drive so that the D: can be found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you boot into safe mode?

then change the location of 'My Doxuments' in the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\
```

edit the path of the value **Personal**